# How to select distinct rows that match multiple elements from same column in 1 query?

Tags: mysql, select

```
ID        object        type
1           1            u            
2           1            x
3           1            z
4           2            z
5           2            t
6           4            x
7           4            u
8           4            t
```

Asuming i have that set of data , what i want to get is all distinct objects that would match some variable number of types, and order them by the number of types that matched. All in 1 query.

So lets say i want the objects that are of type u,x,t . I want to select them in descendent order from the object that matched all to the one that matched only 1 in 1 query. If any1 can help, im using mysql ...

Comment: So, what have you tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here you go:

```
SELECT *, COUNT(ID) AS matches FROM table_name WHERE type IN('u','x','t') GROUP BY object ORDER BY matches DESC
```

Comment: Heh it was so simple :) i was begining to mix up app logic with db logic xD mixing up arrays xD idk what was in my head. Ty alot!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure i understand what you trying todo but i guess it will lead to:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE type IN ('u','x','t') GROUP By object ORDER By object;
```